# Keep whitespace from indent even on empty line

Tags: indentation, whitespace

I am working with python files with `filetype indent on`.  I like a lot of the default indenting features for python, but I would like vim to keep the tabs, even on empty lines.

For example, using `set listchars=space:-,trail:.` and `set list` to show whitespace, and using `_` to show the cursor, if I begin a for-loop or function definition, and hit `<CR>` once, I get this:

```
for-i-in-range(10):
...._
```

And if I start typing something, vim converts the whitespace into spaces and keeps them:

```
for-i-in-range(10):
----print(i)_
```

However, if I hit `<CR>` again, that whitespace is deleted, although vim keeps indenting:

```
for-i-in-range(10):

...._
```

What I would like is for vim to keep the whitespace after I hit `<CR>`, even if there is nothing written on that line.  So typing `for i in range(10):<CR><CR>print(i)` would yield:

```
for-i-in-range(10):
....
----print(i)_
```

Comment: Yeah that helps.  I did a lot of searching, I didnt realize the keyword I should have used was "unindent".  Thanks

Comment: Well, even if you didn't think of "unindent", kudos for trying to find it yourself first. :) If only more people did that.

Comment: BTW, and just FYI, the way I found the linked answer was with google search term `vim leave indent on empty line`. It was the first result. Being more verbose and/or using something closer to a full sentence after the critical keyword (vim) works quite well these days.